# "Can only make proxy for a referenced object to group". This message appears when trying to move any object using the 3D Transform Widget

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

I get this message whenever I try to move any object in Object Mode when using the 3D Transform Widget... "Can only make proxy for a referenced object to group". The "G" key works but not the 3D Transform Widget. The arrows do work in Edit Mode. What can I do to fix this? How did I cause it? I reinstalled Blender but to no avail.
I just created a new file and I can't even move the cube using the arrows!!!

[image: **enter image description here**]

It happens in a new file with the standard cube, as well...

[image]

Comment: How did you create geometry shown on the screenshot? I suppose it's not part of default Blender scene, so you somehow added it? What Blender version do you use? This message could be caused by the fact that objects shown in the scene are linked in the scene and are actually stored in another file, try to go to Properties editor and see if Object, Mesh and Modifiers tabs are grey.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Mr Zak. I think it must be a setting as its happening with a new file with the standard cube. This started out of the blue this afternoon. And it happens with default and linked objects

Comment: I just reloaded factory settings and it's fine now. Thanks